# It is not possible for an entity that requires sessions to create a non-sessionful message receiver

Tags: azure, spring-boot, azureservicebus

Listener

```
@JmsListener(destination = "${servicebus.entities.acsTopicToListen.entityName}", containerFactory = "topicJmsListenerContainerFactory", subscription = "${servicebus.entities.acsTopicToListen.subscriptionName}")
    public void run(byte[] message, Session session) throws Exception {

        try {
            acsDataHandler.messageProcessor(new String(message));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            LOGGER.error("Exception thrown while listening to acsDataTopic...." + ex.getMessage());
            exceptionHelper.handleTransformError(INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "Error from AcsDataReceiver listen()",
                    ACS0001.name(), ex);
        }
```

Configuration

```
    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory schedulerConnectionFactory(ServicebusConnectionProperties serviceBusJMSProperties) {
        final String connectionString = serviceBusJMSProperties.getConnectionString();
        final String clientId = serviceBusJMSProperties.getTopiClientId();
        final int idleTimeout = serviceBusJMSProperties.getIdleTimeout();

        final ServiceBusKey serviceBusKey = ConnectionStringResolver.getServiceBusKey(connectionString);
        final String host = serviceBusKey.getHost();
        final String sasKeyName = serviceBusKey.getSharedAccessKeyName();
        final String sasKey = serviceBusKey.getSharedAccessKey();

        final String remoteUri = String.format(AMQP_URI_FORMAT, host, idleTimeout);
        final JmsConnectionFactory jmsConnectionFactory = new JmsConnectionFactory();
        jmsConnectionFactory.setRemoteURI(remoteUri);
        jmsConnectionFactory.setClientID(clientId);
        jmsConnectionFactory.setUsername(sasKeyName);
        jmsConnectionFactory.setPassword(sasKey);
        return new CachingConnectionFactory(jmsConnectionFactory);
    }

    @Bean
    public Destination destination() {
        return new JmsTopic(destination);
    }

    @Bean
    public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate(ConnectionFactory jmsConnectionFactory, Destination destination) {
        final JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate();
        jmsTemplate.setConnectionFactory(jmsConnectionFactory);
        jmsTemplate.setMessageIdEnabled(true);
        jmsTemplate.setDefaultDestination(destination);
        return jmsTemplate;
    }
    

    @Bean
    public JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> topicJmsListenerContainerFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        final DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        jmsListenerContainerFactory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        jmsListenerContainerFactory.setSubscriptionDurable(Boolean.TRUE);
        jmsListenerContainerFactory.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        return jmsListenerContainerFactory;
    }
```

I am using Azure Service Bus Spring Boot Starter to connect the Servicebus Topic/Subscription which is session enabled , But It's unable to connect with the message below :
**It is not possible for an entity that requires sessions to create a non-sessionful message receiver.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In Java, the session support works with azure-servicebus library example
> QueuesGettingStarted.java by changing queueClient.registerMessageHandler to queueClient.registerSessionHandler and relevant changes.

But in this case please check :
https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus/issues/326#issuecomment-573236250

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-dev-docs/issues/285#issuecomment-699573311

Comment: Thanks Jaya for the quick reply.

Comment: @NilendraMishra if the answer anyhow helped could you please mark it and up vote?